# Synonomize [user-engagement] and [engagement]

Tags: discussion

[engagement](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/engagement) has 9 questions (1 asked this year), and no wiki.

[user-engagement](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-engagement) has 41 questions (2 asked this year), with a wiki.

I suggest we merge [engagement](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/engagement) into [user-engagement](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-engagement) and make the former a synonym for the latter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tag has been merged and synonymized.